# How to change bottom navigation's item icon at runtime?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view which has four items (Home, Search, Notification, Profile). I want if the user has an unread notification the icon of the notification item turns to red. Therefore, I need to change the icon or color icon of the notification item using JAVA codes at runtime. So, my question is how can I change icon of a bottom navigation view at runtime?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`BottomNavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView) element extends [`NavigationBarView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView) which has a [`getMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView#getMenu()) method that returns a [`Menu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu) instance. Once you get your menu, you can retrieve the [`MenuItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem) you want using [`findItem(id)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#findItem(int)) or [`getItem(index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#getItem(int)). Finally, you can alter the icon using the various [`setIcon*()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem#setIcon(int)) methods.

However, notifications should be indicated using the [badges](https://m3.material.io/components/badges/overview). If you want, you can interact with badges at runtime using the [`getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView#getOrCreateBadge(int)) method on your bottom navigation view directly.